# Drupal Views code error

Tags: drupal, view

Every time I try to apply a change in Views (or even cancel a dialogue window for that matter), I get a massive page of code, like this:

!http://reubenlara.com/blog/codeerror.png

When I refresh the page or go use the browser's back button to get to the views panel, everything's fine and the changes are applied. This only happens with Views. Is this happening to anyone else?

Drupal 7.22.21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i just figured it out! I had the jQuery Update installed and had it set to jQuery 1.8. Views did not like that, so I set it to jQuery 1.7 and views is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue because I was using some javascript plugins required some other modules. Please make sure you are not using entityreference views. If you do, you should disable the javascript on your browser using web develop tool bar or similar.

Comment: Hey Josh: I'm unanswering this because, while disabling javascript works, it also disables a bunch of other menu overlays I need working (like admin menu). I uninstalled Entity Reference, but Views is still giving me the error pages when I try to change any views settings. (e.g. Add a filter or field within a views type, or even go into an existing setting and making a change.) Any other ideas?

Comment: Of course! Jquery used by entityreference causes the issue not the entityreference!
This is from my original post:
"I had similar issue because I was using some javascript plugins required some other modules."